# Call rails action from list of elements through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, action

My end goal is to have a user drag items from a list and place it in one of 5 "buckets".  Imagine a list of animals, and you drag dogs and cats into a mammals list, and snakes and iguana to a reptile list, etc.

Using HTML5 Sortable, I am able to have someone drag the item to each list, but it doesn't save the change.  How do I have javascript call the action or route to save the item once it is moved?

This is my main code

```
        <% @cabins.each do |cabin| %>
          <li class="highlight" draggable="true" style="display: list-item;"><%= cabin.name %>-<%= Room.where(name: cabin.name).sum(:clean_time).to_i %></li>
        <% end %>

    </ul>
    Bucket 1
    <ul id="sortable5" class="connected sortable list">
        <li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 1
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 2
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 3
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 4
        </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 5
    </li></ul>
    Bucket 3
    <ul id="sortable5" class="connected sortable list">
        <li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 1
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 2
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 3
        </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 4
        </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 5
    </li></ul>
</section>
```

This is the javascript magic
    
        $(function() {

```
        $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected'

        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried using the code below to call Ajax, but how do I pass a rails variable to it? And what would the route look like?
      $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "/cabins/<%= cabin.id %>"
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of jQuery events in `sortable` that can be used here.

1. change

   ```
   $( ".selector" ).on( "sortchange", function( event, ui ) {} );
   ```
2. sort

   ```
   $( ".selector" ).on( "sort", function( event, ui ) {} );
   ```

Please take a look at this [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) for further help